# How to remove both index.php (homepage) and php (other pages) from URLs with redirects in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, https, seo

My task is the following: I need to remove `index.php` in the URL of the home page and php in the url of all the pages. (Currently I've set up canonical tag for all pages in order to avoid having duplicates).

Solutions tried: I checked out all the answers here on how to remove `index.php` and php in urls.

Issue: However, when I'm using solutions for both in htaccess, just of them works. For example with the code above, I can't remove php in the urls. Additionally, it generates 404 error for some pages. You can see here: https://efficaceweb.fr/referencement-naturel-optimisation-site-seo

And strange URLs are created: `/index.php/audit-site-seo-referencement-naturel.php`

Can any experienced in htaccess coder tell me what's wrong with my code? I would be very very grateful. Thanks in advance.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

#redirect from www

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

#remove php in url

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#remove index php in url

RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,NC]

#https redirect

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

I expect to have redirects both from `index.php` for main page and from `.php` for all other pages working with no bugs and strange urls being generated. Thanks

Comment: Here's my full code in htaccess: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#redirect from www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

#remove index php in url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#https redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

for removing index.php you need to add this in href

```
<a href="/"></a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="/index.php"></a>
```

and for removing .php from url you need to put the .htaccess in root directory and inside root you need

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

and then remove the .php from link href like
`<a href="post"></a>` remove .php

Comment: Thanks Bilawal for your post. However, I don't have <a href="/index.php"></a>. I do have <a href="/"></a>. And I don't have .php in my code. You can check in source code. Btw it doesn't solve the issue cause it's just a link. In my menu and in all the navigation I have short URLs, without .php. My issue is to make a redirect 301 from .php to non-.php. Thanks

Comment: I have tried your code and this code  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] ... but no of them works